# partitioning numbers from 1 to n in 4 non-empty subsets so no subset has 2 consecutive numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Attempt: We have to find the number of ways to partition the numbers 1 to n into four non-empty subsets so that none of them are empty. let $f(n)$ be the way to do that and let $f'(n)$ be the way to partition into 3 none-empty subsets so that none of them contains consecutive integers.

first off we know $f(4)=1,f'(3)=1$

Recursive relations:

$f(n)=3f(n-1)+f'(n-1)$

$f'(n)=2f'(n-1)+1$

The second relation is well-known and tabulating some values we find it is $2^{n-2}-1$ for $n\geq3$. Using this we rewrite the first recursion as:

$f(n)=3f(n-1)+2^{n-3}-1$

but here I am stuck.

Comment: The general solution of that recurrence will be $f(n)=A\,3^n+B\,2^n+C$ for some constants $B$ and $C$, with $A$ arbitrary.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning leading to the recurrence.

Comment: the reasoning behind the recurrence is that if you ignore the last number then you can either have a restricted partition on 4 parts or on 3 parts. If it is in 4 parts then the last element can be added to any of the 4 partitions except the one to which the second to last one belongs. If it is a partition in 3 parts then you have to add the last number to the new partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what you have is [Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,3)$](https://oeis.org/A000392).

Comment: could you tell me why that is what I have?

Comment: I found a solution by counting two ways, and I also found that the recurrences are the same, thanks a lot. This new solution shows me that perhaps the way I should have tackled the problem was transforming the problem.

Comment: Not really, they count partitions without the extra restriction of not containing adyacent elements.

Comment: I will add an answer explaining the reasonings.

Comment: I hope my reasoning makes sense.

Comment: @vonbrand, it appears that the number of unrestricted partitions into 3 parts equals the number of restricted partitions into 4 parts.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful, user4140. You do have the option of voting it up.

Comment: I voted up, but I would like a way of calculating S(n,3) without recursion, is that possible? Alos, how did you realize they where the same? The recursion or a transformation?(ie bijection)?

Comment: Sure, you just solve that recurrence. I gave you the general form of the solution in my comment on the question, you just have to work out $A,B,C$. And I think you'll find they've been worked out for you at the oeis page in my answer. Also, you can work out $S(n,3)$ by inclusion-exclusion, so there's a third way to get the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized this function was not-well defined and that the eqivalence is between $4rp(n)$ and $S(n-1,3)$. I will be fixing it briefly